# android - progress bar is not dismissed properly

Tags: android, thread-safety

In `OnResume()`, I make web service call in thread here i used progress bar for indicating the process it works fine but suppose i uses the app after sometime i put the device idle after that open the app once again this time progress bar is not dismissed.It's not regularly happens sometimes it happens. Why?
How can i make it to away from this? If you need more info plz let me know.

**Code :**

**Edit:**

```
public void onResume()
{

    super.onResume();
    pdMessages = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "", "Please wait...", true);
            Thread thImportbtn = new Thread() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Get internal messages
                        strInternalInboxWSR = GetInternalInboxMessages();


                    } catch (SoapFault e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   

                    dh_Messages_Handler.post(checked_internalinbox_response);
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                }                                               
            };
            thImportbtn.start();       
}
```

private Handler handler = new Handler()
{

```
@Override
public void handleMessage ( Message message )
{
    pdMessages.dismiss();
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `Trying To Dismiss ProgressDialog in Non-UI Thread,` So can't Dismiss proper.

you should put your dismiss code( `pdMessages.dismiss();`) in Handler Using Overriding `handleMessage method`

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is better.

Comment: It means if you update the UI part based on the data from the background process For this type of scenario better to use AsyncTask right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Handler Class to dismiss your ProgressDialog, like below

```
private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage ( Message message )
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

you can use following statement to call Handler class,

```
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
```

Comment: @naresh, thanks for mentioning it, i have updated my answer, please check it.